# I'm facing an issue while installing WordPress on my local server

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, xampp, lamp

"Hello everyone. I'm facing an issue while installing WordPress on my local server. What's the problem? Let me explain in detail. First, I installed LAMP (`sudo pacman -S apache php php-apache`). Then, I started and enabled Apache and MariaDB

```
sudo systemctl start httpd 
sudo systemctl enable httpd 
sudo systemctl start mariadb 
sudo systemctl enable mariadb
```

After that, I configured MariaDB by running the setup wizard (`sudo mysql_secure_installation`). Following that, I accessed http://localhost and everything worked fine. Next, I created a new database and a new user. Then, I downloaded WordPress, extracted the archive, and went to the WordPress directory. I copied the configuration file according to the manual (`sudo cp wp-config-sample.php wp-config.php`) and edited it (changed the database name to the one created earlier, changed the username and password). When I opened https://localhost/wordpress, I didn't see the initial WordPress setup page. Instead, I saw just a file directory listing of the WordPress directory (index of /wordpress). What did I do wrong, and how can I access my WordPress on my local server?"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.